# Design of multi-threaded networking notifications in C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, networking, server

Basically there are a couple operational modes that my program can be in, each of them requiring initialization then updating. Each mode has its own configuration struct.

How can I after receiving a message and determining what mode its describing notify the main thread to initialize then start updating that mode? (I'm looking for an outline of the best way to do it in C++17)

To clarify, it is a daemon application. After initialization, the main thread's **only** job is to do the calculations required by mode updates. The networking is done on a separate worker thread with Boost.Asio. I also expect (as I am writing the client side program as well) that the frequency of mode changes will be low (~10hz max), so I want to avoid the use of a queue since the modes are for controlling the behavior of a robot, and a queue would add latency.

Comment: You can have a notification queue in the main thread and use condition variables to notify the main thread when a received message is pushed into the queue.

Comment: It is hard to say without knowing more about your mainthread. Does it have a mainloop, message queue? etc.. etc..

Comment: I already answered, but perhaps a bit prematurely.  Is your application a GUI program with a UI?  That changes everything.  Or is it a console/daemon that where the main thread can remain paused while the background work is completed?  How is this background thread doing the networking getting started anyway?

Comment: I added additional information in the question.

Comment: Is the mainthread running a (control) loop or not? E.g. does it have a while loop that checks conditions and runs other code when needed? Or what prevents the mainthread from exiting your program directly?

Comment: The program runs indefinitely, as it is a systemd service. I am looking for a way to make a main loop that runs some init(config) function every time a config is received and runs update() until the next one.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your main thread can just sit and wait for the network download to complete before it starts the main code, you can use a [std::condition_variable](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable)

Your main thread does this:

```
std::condition_variable cv;
std::mutex mut;
bool networkOperationCompleted;
Config globalconfig;

int main()
{
     // initialize whatever kicks off the network thread

     std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lck(mut);
     while (networkOperationCompleted == false)
     {
         cv.wait();
     }
}
```

meanwhile, your network thread does this:

```
extern std::condition_variable cv;
extern std::mutex mut;
extern bool networkOperationCompleted;
extern Config globalconfig;

void background_task()
{

     Config config;
     DownloadTheConfig(&config);
     {
         std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lck(m);
         globalConfig = config;
         networkOperationComplete = true;
         cv.notify_all();
     }
}
```

Comment: How would this look in a loop? I mean if I had an "init(config)" and "update()" function in main() how could I always init on config download and keep updating after until another config is downlaoded? What would the loop conditions look like?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up going with something like this:

```cpp
class config
{
public:
    using empty = std::monostate;

    struct modeA
    {
        ...
    };

    struct modeB
    {
        ...
    };

    template<typename T, typename Lambda>
    void handle(Lambda&& handler) const
    {
        if (std::holds_alternative<T>(storage))
        {
            handler(std::get<T>(storage));
        }
    }

    void clear()
    {
        storage = empty{};
    }

private:
    std::variant<empty, modeA, modeB> storage;
};

config server::pop_cfg()
{
    std::unique_lock lock{cfg_mutex};
    config copy{cfg};
    cfg.clear();
    return copy;
}

int main()
{
    ...

    mode* mode;
    while (true)
    {
        config cfg = server.pop_cfg();
        
        cfg.handle<config::empty>([&](...) {
            mode->update();
        });
        
        cfg.handle<config::modeA>([&](config::modeA cfg) {
            mode = new ModeA(cfg);
        });
        
        cfg.handle<config::modeB>([&](config::modeB cfg) {
            mode = new ModeB(cfg);
        });
    }
}
```